# Setting up column values based on other column values- Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Firstly, I do not know JavaScript. But to make my app more efficient, I need to do some Cloud Code in Parse (I'm using Parse as my backend for my Android app).

Can anyone write a simple script where I can set the value of a column (lets call it column A) of a table based on a value in another column (say column B) and the last value of the same column (column A)?

Essentially,

columnA_value = someOperation(columnB_value,previousValue(columnA))

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.someOperation = function() {
  var columnB_value = $('td:nth-child(2)');  // grab the second number
  var a = getNumber(columnB_value.prev());  // grab and parse first number
  var b = getNumber(columnB_value);  // parse second number
  columnB_value.next().html(a + b);  // add numbers, put them in column 3
}

window.getNumber = function(dom_element) {
    return parseInt(dom_element.html());  //  get contents of td, parse it into number
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
    <td>
      ?
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="someOperation()">Compute</button>
```